# How Plot this Region

Tags: plotting, regions

Given this function:

$$f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$$

Sketch the image under $f$ of the set:

$$S=\left\{(x,y)\:|\: x^2+y^2 \leq a^2 \:\&\&\: x\geq 0 \:\&\&\:  y\geq 0 \right\}$$

Comment: Convert to polar coordinates?

Comment: is this even a mathematica question? Whats an "imagem"?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this:

```
Block[{a = 2},
 ParametricPlot[{x^2 - y^2, 2 x y}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, a, {0, Pi/2}]]
 ]
```

*Update:*
Perhaps an answer to @Rom38's region interpretation:

```
Block[{a = 2},
 RegionPlot@
  ParametricRegion[{{x^2 - y^2, 2 x y}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, a, {0, Pi/2}]}, {x, y}]
 ]
```

Comment: To show the output seems a bit of a spoiler to me.  This is a nice, easy exercise by hand or in one's head.

Comment: You've missed the condition x>=0 and y>=0

Comment: @Rom38 Yeah, I guess doing someone else homework completely is better for the world than leaving such details for the reader....Anyway someone else couldn't resist, so why not add the missing restriction?  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I've pointed it out because on my view the question was more about region definition than about plotting of the functions. But I agree with you - the solution of school tasks is not for this site.

Comment: @Rom38 I've updated my answer in response to your interpretation to the question being about regions.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[{x^2 - y^2, 2 x y}, {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, Sqrt[a^2 - x^2]}, 
    PlotPoints -> 60], 
  {{a, 1}, 0.1, 10}]
```